Draggable nodes in JTree
This is the TransferHandler code I found here.
JTree is completely draggable, but the problem is that when I move one of the nodes, in the place where I put that node, two nodes are added instead of one.
For example, there are two nodes category1 and category2 in JTree, when I put category2 into category1, two categories2 are added inside category1.
public class TreeTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {
    private DataFlavor nodesFlavor;
    private DataFlavor[] flavors;
    private DefaultMutableTreeNode[] nodesToRemove;

    public TreeTransferHandler() {
        try {
            String mimeType = DataFlavor.javaJVMLocalObjectMimeType + ";class=\"" + DefaultMutableTreeNode[].class.getName() + "\"";
            nodesFlavor = new DataFlavor(mimeType);
            flavors = new DataFlavor[]{nodesFlavor};
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("ClassNotFound: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canImport(TransferSupport support) {
        if (!support.isDrop())
            return false;

        support.setShowDropLocation(true);

        if (!support.isDataFlavorSupported(nodesFlavor))
            return false;

        JTree.DropLocation dl = (JTree.DropLocation) support.getDropLocation();
        JTree tree = (JTree) support.getComponent();

        int dropRow = tree.getRowForPath(dl.getPath());
        int[] selRows = tree.getSelectionRows();

        for (int selRow : selRows)
            if (selRow == dropRow)
                return false;

        int action = support.getDropAction();
        if (action == MOVE)
            return haveCompleteNode(tree);

        TreePath dest = dl.getPath();
        DefaultMutableTreeNode targetNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) dest.getLastPathComponent();

        TreePath path = tree.getPathForRow(selRows[0]);
        DefaultMutableTreeNode firstNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) path.getLastPathComponent();
        if (firstNode.getChildCount() > 0 && targetNode.getLevel() < firstNode.getLevel())
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    private boolean haveCompleteNode(JTree tree) {
        int[] selRows = tree.getSelectionRows();
        TreePath path = tree.getPathForRow(selRows[0]);
        DefaultMutableTreeNode firstNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)path.getLastPathComponent();
        int childCount = firstNode.getChildCount();

        if(childCount > 0 && selRows.length == 1)
            return false;

        for(int i = 1; i < selRows.length; i++) {
            path = tree.getPathForRow(selRows[i]);
            DefaultMutableTreeNode next = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)path.getLastPathComponent();

            if (firstNode.isNodeChild(next))
                if (childCount > selRows.length - 1)
                    return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean importData(TransferSupport support) {
        if (!canImport(support))
            return false;

        DefaultMutableTreeNode[] nodes = null;
        try {
            Transferable transferable = support.getTransferable();
            nodes = (DefaultMutableTreeNode[]) transferable.getTransferData(nodesFlavor);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JTree.DropLocation dl = (JTree.DropLocation) support.getDropLocation();
        TreePath dest = dl.getPath();
        DefaultMutableTreeNode parent = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) dest.getLastPathComponent();
        JTree tree = (JTree) support.getComponent();
        DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel();

        int index = dl.getChildIndex();
        int childCount = parent.getChildCount();

        if (index == -1)
            index = childCount;

        for (DefaultMutableTreeNode node: nodes) {
            model.insertNodeInto(node, parent, index++);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c) {
        JTree tree = (JTree) c;
        TreePath[] paths = tree.getSelectionPaths();

        if (paths != null) {
            List<DefaultMutableTreeNode> copies = new ArrayList<>();
            List<DefaultMutableTreeNode> toRemove = new ArrayList<>();

            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) paths[0].getLastPathComponent();
            DefaultMutableTreeNode copy = copy(node);

            copies.add(copy);
            toRemove.add(node);

            for (TreePath path: paths) {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode next = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) path.getLastPathComponent();
                if (next.getLevel() < node.getLevel())
                    break;
                else if (next.getLevel() > node.getLevel())
                    copy.add(copy(next));
                else {
                    copies.add(copy(next));
                    toRemove.add(next);
                }
            }

            DefaultMutableTreeNode[] nodes = copies.toArray(new DefaultMutableTreeNode[copies.size()]);
            nodesToRemove = toRemove.toArray(new DefaultMutableTreeNode[toRemove.size()]);
            return new NodesTransferable(nodes);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private DefaultMutableTreeNode copy(DefaultMutableTreeNode node) {
        return (DefaultMutableTreeNode) node.clone();
    }

    @Override
    protected void exportDone(JComponent source, Transferable data, int action) {
        if ((action & MOVE) == MOVE) {
            JTree tree = (JTree) source;
            DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel();
            for (DefaultMutableTreeNode node: nodesToRemove)
                model.removeNodeFromParent(node);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
        return COPY_OR_MOVE;
    }

    private class NodesTransferable implements Transferable {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode[] nodes;

        public NodesTransferable(DefaultMutableTreeNode[] nodes) {
            this.nodes = nodes;
        }

        @Override
        public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
            return flavors;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
            return nodesFlavor.equals(flavor);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor) throws UnsupportedFlavorException {
            if (!isDataFlavorSupported(flavor))
                throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(flavor);
            return nodes;
        }
    }
}

